# Are delayed messages in Redis reliable?

Tags: redis, queue, message-queue, laravel-queue, delayed-execution

I have an architecture solution that relies on the delayed messages.

In short:
There are many clients (mostly mobile devices running android or ios) that can process a given job.

I am creating a job delegation (in RDBMS) for a given client expecting it to be picked up within a certain period of time and the "chosen" client receives a push notification that there is something for it to process. IMO the details about the algorithm of choosing single client out of many is irrelevant to the problem so skipping this part.

When the client pulls a job delegation then the status of it is changed from pending to processing.
As mentioned clients are mobile devices and are often carried by people in move and thus can, due to many reasons, be unable to pull the job delegation from the server and process it.

That's why during the creation of the job delegation, there is also a delayed message dispatched in Redis which is supposed to check in now() + 40 seconds if the job was pulled or not (so if the status is pending or not).

If the delegation hasn't been pulled by the client (status = pending) server times it out and creates a new job delegation with status = pending for a different client. As so on as so for.

It works pretty well except the fact that I've noticed the "check if should timeout" jobs do not ALWAYS run at the time I would expect them to be run. The average is 7 seconds later and the max is 29 seconds later for the analyzed sample of few thousands of jobs. Redis is used as a queue but also as a key-value cache store and in general heavily utilized by the system. May it become that much impacted by the load? I've sort of "reproduced" the issue also on my local environment with a containerized setup with much less load so I doubt it's entirely due to the Redis being busy.

The delay in execution (vs expected) is quite a problem here because it may happen that, especially in case of trying few clients from the list, the total time since creation of the job till it's successfully processed can increase a lot.

So back to the original question. Is the delayed messaging functionality in Redis reliable?

Are there any good recommended docs about it?
Are there any more reliable solutions designed to solve that issue?

Expecting that messages set to be executed in a given timestamp is executed no later than 2-3 seconds from that timestamp.

Comment: Just in case you got here ;) 
Let's say it is solved because I've finally found the source problem and it has nothing to do with Redis. 
It was caused by the way Laravel workers have been setup (with a 20 seconds sleep interval). I would never suspect such setup and actually accidentally spotted it when browsing the supervisor configuration.
So in our case the solution is to create a dedicated queue and a worker with a 1s sleep interval.